# Dudes about parsable output in atop

Tags: linux

I'm trying to analyze the parseable output from atop, but the man section is not clearly to me, I count more words than manual page explain.

"The first part of each output-line consists of the following six fields: label (the name of the label), host (the name of this machine), epoch (the time of this interval as number of seconds since 1-1-1970), date (date of this interval in format YYYY/MM/DD), time (time of this interval in format HH:MM:SS), and interval (number of seconds elapsed for this interval).
The subsequent fields of each output-line depend on the label:

PRM:

Subsequent fields: PID, name (between brackets), state, page size for this machine (in bytes), virtual memory size (Kbytes), resident memory size (Kbytes), shared text memory size (Kbytes), virtual memory growth (Kbytes), resident memory growth (Kbytes), number of minor page faults, and number of major page faults."

https://linux.die.net/man/1/atop

So,
Standard fields + PRM fields

```
6   +   11  = 17
```

But I count 24 fields total

`atop -r FILE -p PRM`

sample output;

```
PRM hernan-Virtual-Machine 1591135517 2020/06/02 19:05:17 834 660
 (cron) S 4096 38424 3288 44 38424 3288 247 1 3216 336 132 0 660 y 385
```

How should i read the output?

Comment: Does `man atop` on your machine give the same description as the one in the link?

Comment: this is very embarrassing i am using a different version x.x

Comment: Not at all, it happens often to all of us. Usually, the difference is so small we don't even notice.